# Drawing 2d isometric image grid

Tags: multidimensional-array, processing, isometric

I've been trying to represent a 2d array of images as an isometric grid in Processing, however I cannot seem to get their placement right.

The images do not get placed next to each other (as in, the tiles do not touch), even though the x and y points seem to indicate they should be (as the cartesian view works and the isometric conversion equations seem to be correct).

Here is what I mean:

[image: Isometric grid]

I think I may be treating my translations and rotations wrong, but after hours of googling I cannot find how.

My full code for this implementation can be seen [here](http://codepaste.net/yatsgb). This is full Processing code and over complicated, but a simpler version can be seen below.

```java
color grass = color(20, 255, 20);  //Grass tiles lay within wall tiles. These are usually images, but here they are colours for simplicity
color wall = color(150, 150, 150);

void setup() {
size(600, 600);
noLoop();
}

void draw() {
 int rectWidth = 30;
 float scale = 2;  //Used to grow the shapes larger
 float gap = rectWidth * scale;  //The gap between each "tile", to allow tile s to fit next to each other
 int rows = 4, cols = 4;  //How many rows and columns there are in the grid

 translate(300, 200);

 for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
    /* x and y calculations */
    float cartesianX = col * gap;  //The standard cartesian x and y points. These place the tiles next to each other on the cartesian plane
    float cartesianY = row * gap;

    float isometricX = (cartesianX - cartesianY);  //The isometric x and y points. The equations calculate it from the cartesian ones
    float isometricY = (cartesianX + cartesianY) / 2;

    /* transformations and placement */
    pushMatrix();  //Pushes the transform and rotate matrix onto a stack, allowing it to be reset after each loop

    translate(isometricX, isometricY);  //Translate to the point that the tile needs to be placed.
    scale(scale, scale / 2);  //Scale the tile, making it twice as wide as it is high
    rotate(radians(45));  //Rotate the tile into place

    //Work out what colour to set the box to
    if (row == 0 || col == 0 || row == rows -1 || col == cols - 1)  fill(wall);
    else fill(grass);

    rect(0, 0, rectWidth, rectWidth);

    popMatrix();
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look closer at how you're using two values:

```
int rectWidth = 30;
```

This is the size of the rectangles. Makes sense.

```
float gap = rectWidth * scale;
```

This is the distance between the left sides of the rectangle. In other words, you're using these to place the rectangles. **When this is greater than the size of the rectangles, you'll have space between the rectangles.** And since you're multiplying `rectWidth` by `scale` (which is `2`), it's going to be greater than `rectWidth`.

In other words, if you make your `gap` equal to `rectWidth`, you don't get any spaces:

```
float gap = rectWidth;
```

[image: isometric grid without gaps]

Of course, that means you can probably get rid of your `gap` variable entirely, but it might come in handy if you want to space the rectangles out to make their borders thicker or something.

Comment: Your fix does bring the tiles together, however I notice that they overlap now instead of not touching. I assume that for a proper isometric view, they must be directly next to each other and not overlapping. 

Here is an example of what I mean:
[Isometric Overlap](http://i.imgur.com/ULA21Kx.png).

Is there a fix for this? Also, is there any way to make the code so that I can change the scale and have the tiles move together, just so I can experiment with how I want it to look?

Also, I just want to say thank you very much for editing my post, it is much appreciated :)

Comment: @AlexHockley No problem. If `gap=rectWidth` is too close together, you could try adding a buffer: `gap=rectWidth+12` seems to work pretty well. Not sure where that magic number is coming from, but I've also never seen isometric view done this way. Not saying you're doing it wrong! As for the scale, I'm guessing that you'd need to base your magic number off the scale. Maybe `12*scale` would be the first dumb thing to try. I'd love to help if you have more questions, but it might be easier if you post them as new questions, since Stack Overflow comments are (purposely) terrible.

Comment: That fix works very well, even if it's a bit more manual than I was planning on. Thank you very much, I'll follow your advice and post a new question if I get stuck again.